# Нужно приклеить футер и при добавлении контента чтобы он не гулял в пространстве

Tags: html, html5, layout, float, resize

Необходмо приклеить футер к низу экрана, чтобы при скроллинге разрешения экрана он не гулял в воздухе и не налазил на контент сайта, при этом если добавляешь картинки или блоки в середину(контент) футер не налазит на него, так же,чтобы при удалении тоже ничего не рушилось.

Решил скинуть код для удобства сюда -->  https://jsfiddle.net/wjqoqgtg/

Благодарю заранее!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="main" class="clear-fix">
    <header id="header">
        <img src="img/img.jpg" class="logo-img" alt="logo" title="logo.jpg">
        <div class="div-two"></div>
        <div class="div-three"></div>
    </header>
    <span class="divider"></span>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
            <aside class="aside-top"><p>Создание сайтов</p></aside>
            <img src="img/img.jpg" class="aside-bottom" alt="aside-bottom img" title="aside.jpg">
        </div>
        <main id="center">
            <article class="top-article">
                <div class="block-text">
                    <h3>PSD файл с макетом. Макет разбит по слоям и сгруппирован по папкам:</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><strong>number</strong> - нумерация блоков (номера блоков верстать не нужнно)</li>
                        <li><strong>text</strong> - текстовые блоки (шрифт Arial, размер 14 пикселей, межстрочное расстояние 22 пикселя)</li>
                        <li><strong>head</strong> - шапка сайта</li>
                        <li><strong>content</strong> - контентная область, которая в свою очередь делится на <strong>left</strong> и <strong>center</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>Текстовое описание задания и требования</p>
                </div>
            </article>
            <article class="center-article">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
            </article>
            <article class="bottom-article">
                <div class="block-advert"></div>
                <div class="block-advert"><p>Поисковое продвижение (раскрутка) ведется по коммерческим запросам, что позволяет много-<br>кратно увеличить количество продаж с сайта при разумном рекламном бюджете</p></div>
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
   <footer id="footer">
    <span class="divider-bottom"></span>
    <div class="footer-block">
        <ul class="footer-list">
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 08</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 02</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 09</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 03</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 04</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 05</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 06</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 07</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 14</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-block">
        <ul class="footer-rate">
            <li><a href="#">Поисковое продвижение сайтов</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Старт&raquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Продвижение Плюс&raquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Интернет-магазин&raquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Эксклюзив&raquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Контекст + SEO&raquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Регион&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-block-right"></div>
    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="footer-block-right" alt="footer-block-right img" title="footer-bottom.jpg">
```

Comment: position: fixed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}
#wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще свой вариант с `absolute`:

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

body {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
/* html, body, #wrapper { height: 100%; } */
body > #wrapper {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#main {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}

.clear-fix:before,
.clear-fix:after {
  content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear-fix:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clear-fix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clear-fix {
    display: block;
}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
#wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1024px;
    min-width:960px;
}
#header{
    clear: both;
    height: 150px;
}
#content{
    margin-top:20px;
}

.logo-img, .div-two, .div-three{
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
}
.logo-img{
    width:100px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.div-two{
    width:300px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.div-three{
    width:540px;
    background-color: #777;
}
#left{
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: -16px;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 125px;
}
.aside-top{
    height:300px;
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
}
.aside-top p{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 15px;

}
.aside-bottom{
    margin-top:400px;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #777;
    clear: both;
}
#center{
    float: right;
    width: 808px;
    /* height: 800px; */
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.top-article{
    clear: both;
}
.center-article{
    clear: both;
}
.bottom-article{
    clear: both;
}
.top-article {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.block-text{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    color: #757575;
    height: 200px;
    width: 780px;
    font-size: 14px;
    content: inherit;
    clear: both;

}
.block-text h3{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.block-text ul{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left: 65px;
}
.block-text p{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.block{
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    width: 136px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    vertical-align: top;

}
.block-advert{
    float: left;
    height: 205px;
    width: 382px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.block-advert p{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #757575;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    width: 960px;
    clear:both;
    color: white;
    padding: 48px 0;
}

#footer ul{
    margin-top:10px;
}
.footer-block{
    width: 290px;
    height: 230px;
    background-color: #777;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
.footer-block-right{
    width: 325px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #777;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.footer-list li{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    list-style: none;
}
.footer-list li>a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.footer-list li>a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.footer-rate li{
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 35px;
}
.footer-rate li>a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-rate li>a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.divider{
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #7B7B7B;
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.divider-bottom{
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #7B7B7B;
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="clear-fix">
    <div id="main" class="clear-fix">
        <header id="header">
            <img src="img/img.jpg" class="logo-img" alt="logo" title="logo.jpg">
            <div class="div-two"></div>
            <div class="div-three"></div>
        </header>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <div id="content" class="clear-fix">
            <div id="left" class="clear-fix">
                <aside class="aside-top"><p>Создание сайтов</p></aside>
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="aside-bottom" alt="aside-bottom img" title="aside.jpg">
            </div>
            <main id="center" class="clear-fix">
                <article class="top-article clear-fix">
                    <div class="block-text">
                        <h3>PSD файл с макетом. Макет разбит по слоям и сгруппирован по папкам:</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><strong>number</strong> - нумерация блоков (номера блоков верстать не нужнно)</li>
                            <li><strong>text</strong> - текстовые блоки (шрифт Arial, размер 14 пикселей, межстрочное расстояние 22 пикселя)</li>
                            <li><strong>head</strong> - шапка сайта</li>
                            <li><strong>content</strong> - контентная область, которая в свою очередь делится на <strong>left</strong> и <strong>center</strong></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>Текстовое описание задания и требования</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="center-article clear-fix">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                    <!--<img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">-->
                </article>
                <article class="bottom-article clear-fix">
                    <div class="block-advert"></div>
                    <div class="block-advert"><p>Поисковое продвижение (раскрутка) ведется по коммерческим запросам, что позволяет много-<br>кратно увеличить количество продаж с сайта при разумном рекламном бюджете</p></div>
                </article>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="divider-bottom"></span>
        <div class="footer-block">
            <ul class="footer-list">
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 01</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 08</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 02</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 09</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 03</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 04</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 05</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 06</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 07</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 14</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-block">
            <ul class="footer-rate">
                <li><a href="#">Поисковое продвижение сайтов</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Старт&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Продвижение Плюс&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Интернет-магазин&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Эксклюзив&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Контекст + SEO&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Регион&raquo;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-block-right"></div>
        <img src="img/img.jpg" class="footer-block-right" alt="footer-block-right img" title="footer-bottom.jpg">
    </div>
</footer>
```

Убрала стили - `html, body, #wrapper { height: 100%; }` , на этой стр. не понятно для чего они.

`body` (родителю для футера) добавила `position: relative` и отступ под высоту подвала - 300px

`footer` соответственно добавила абсолютное позиционирование c `bottom: 0`.

Поправила стили `clearfix` и добавила его всем блокам содержащим внутри плавающие блоки.

`#center` - убрала фиксированную высоту, контент явно не на 800px, а больше.

**Вариант 2** - без позиционирования ,в общем потоке:

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

/* body {
  position: relative;
padding-bottom: 300px;
} */
/* html, body, #wrapper { height: 100%; } */
body > #wrapper {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#main {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
}

.clear-fix:before,
.clear-fix:after {
  content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear-fix:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clear-fix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clear-fix {
    display: block;
}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
#wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1024px;
    min-width:960px;
}
#header{
    clear: both;
    height: 150px;
}
#content{
    margin-top:20px;
}

.logo-img, .div-two, .div-three{
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    float: left;
}
.logo-img{
    width:100px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.div-two{
    width:300px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.div-three{
    width:540px;
    background-color: #777;
}
#left{
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: -16px;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 125px;
}
.aside-top{
    height:300px;
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
}
.aside-top p{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 15px;

}
.aside-bottom{
    margin-top:400px;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #777;
    clear: both;
}
#center{
    float: right;
    width: 808px;
    /* height: 800px; */
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.top-article{
    clear: both;
}
.center-article{
    clear: both;
}
.bottom-article{
    clear: both;
}
.top-article {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.block-text{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    color: #757575;
    height: 200px;
    width: 780px;
    font-size: 14px;
    content: inherit;
    clear: both;

}
.block-text h3{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.block-text ul{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left: 65px;
}
.block-text p{
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.block{
    float: left;
    height: 160px;
    width: 136px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    vertical-align: top;

}
.block-advert{
    float: left;
    height: 205px;
    width: 382px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.block-advert p{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #757575;
}
#footer {
    /* position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    width: 960px;
    clear:both;
    color: white;
    padding: 48px 0;
}

#footer ul{
    margin-top:10px;
}
.footer-block{
    width: 290px;
    height: 230px;
    background-color: #777;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
.footer-block-right{
    width: 325px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #777;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.footer-list li{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    list-style: none;
}
.footer-list li>a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.footer-list li>a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.footer-rate li{
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 35px;
}
.footer-rate li>a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-rate li>a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.divider{
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #7B7B7B;
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.divider-bottom{
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid #7B7B7B;
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="clear-fix">
    <div id="main" class="clear-fix">
        <header id="header">
            <img src="img/img.jpg" class="logo-img" alt="logo" title="logo.jpg">
            <div class="div-two"></div>
            <div class="div-three"></div>
        </header>
        <span class="divider"></span>
        <div id="content" class="clear-fix">
            <div id="left" class="clear-fix">
                <aside class="aside-top"><p>Создание сайтов</p></aside>
                <img src="img/img.jpg" class="aside-bottom" alt="aside-bottom img" title="aside.jpg">
            </div>
            <main id="center" class="clear-fix">
                <article class="top-article clear-fix">
                    <div class="block-text">
                        <h3>PSD файл с макетом. Макет разбит по слоям и сгруппирован по папкам:</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><strong>number</strong> - нумерация блоков (номера блоков верстать не нужнно)</li>
                            <li><strong>text</strong> - текстовые блоки (шрифт Arial, размер 14 пикселей, межстрочное расстояние 22 пикселя)</li>
                            <li><strong>head</strong> - шапка сайта</li>
                            <li><strong>content</strong> - контентная область, которая в свою очередь делится на <strong>left</strong> и <strong>center</strong></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>Текстовое описание задания и требования</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="center-article clear-fix">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                    <img src="img/img.jpg" class="block" alt="center-article img" title="center-article.jpg">
                </article>
                <article class="bottom-article clear-fix">
                    <div class="block-advert"></div>
                    <div class="block-advert"><p>Поисковое продвижение (раскрутка) ведется по коммерческим запросам, что позволяет много-<br>кратно увеличить количество продаж с сайта при разумном рекламном бюджете</p></div>
                </article>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="divider-bottom"></span>
        <div class="footer-block">
            <ul class="footer-list">
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 01</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 08</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 02</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 09</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 03</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 10</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 04</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 05</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 06</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 07</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 14</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-block">
            <ul class="footer-rate">
                <li><a href="#">Поисковое продвижение сайтов</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Старт&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Продвижение Плюс&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Интернет-магазин&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Эксклюзив&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Контекст + SEO&raquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Тариф &laquo;Регион&raquo;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-block-right"></div>
        <img src="img/img.jpg" class="footer-block-right" alt="footer-block-right img" title="footer-bottom.jpg">
    </div>
</footer>
```

все выстраивается друг за другом и футер в самом низу после всего контента.

Comment: Согласен, я там уже такого перемудрил (засорил страшно код) что сам запутался. Кстати да, у меня точно так же получилось с самого начала как у Вас, но это все равно не решает проблемы с тем что при скролинге разрешения (допустим если в центре блоков с картинками 10 штук) а zoom в браузере порядка 50% то фтуер отлипается от низа страницы и улетает вверх.

Comment: @NotControlledMind, zoom 50% http://prntscr.com/eq187r   и так же проверила с большим кол-вом картинок

Comment: Я так думаю, что можно обойтись и без абсолютного позиционирования подвала, просто нужно посмотреть чтобы все блоки     плавающие блоки были правильно обернуты, сейчас добавлю вариант

Comment: У меня вот такая бяка поулчается :) в Mozilla Developers http://prnt.sc/eq1cv4 и в Google Chrome http://prnt.sc/eq1cnk

Comment: @NotControlledMind, а вот тут http://prnt.sc/eq1cnk бяка в чем? Футер же внизу я смотрю?

Comment: кстати зум не очень хорошее решение при проверке, лучше задавать необходимые разрешения в панели разработчика (эмулятор девайсов), но это так если что

Comment: Бяка в том, что по правилам он не должен отлипать от низа страницы, в ином случае такая верстка считается неправильной. Да про панель разработчика знаю, использую вообще Mozilla Developer Edition + Firebug

Comment: @NotControlledMind, ну тогда `fixed` )

Comment: Fixed в моем случае не очень подходит, "плюсую" Вам за старания и потраченное время :) Я просто сейчас так углубился в изучение JS, что позабыл все эти хаки в верстке, вот никак не могу вспомнить как реализовать то, что хочу, хотя помню, что делал такое и футер не болтался в воздухе и контент добавлялся на ура и все нормально себя чувствовало, хотя может мне это все просто приснилось, в любом случае хочу сказать Вам спасибо, что откликнулись :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 960px;
    clear:both;
    color: white;
}
```